# Copy browser and it settings to a new machine

Tags: centos

I have a machine running on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) with kernel Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 .

I want to copy my opera and firefox browser all the settings to a new system as it contains a my old logins etc which i don;t have a recovery for those logins. Since im planning to install the OS again i want to keep all my settings etc same as my present machine .
Few question

- Is it possible to copy use it on a new machine with all the configuration which I'm using .
- If yes do i need to reinstall the browser again or i can simple launch the already compiled program?

Comment: Your personal settings like passwords, certificates etc. are stored as a profile in the user's home directory, for firefox it is under `/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/`, see [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) for more information on what your profile containts, and [here's](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/backup-and-restore-a-firefox-profile-on-linux/) a discription how to save the profile and restore it again. You should definitely install the browser and then use the old profile. Be careful with different versions of firefox.

Comment: And for chrome you can take a look at [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/backup-and-restore-a-firefox-profile-on-linux/).

Comment: what about opera ?..for chorme i have synced everything so its not an issue..so i have to keep the OS version same  its not like i can transfer my browser profile from centos to Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried "Menu > About Opera"? According to google search this shows you the different paths. I don't have an opera browser available right now.

Comment: the folder is located in the /usr/lib64 so there it might contain the profile login etc not sure how to work on it

Comment: @krushnachChandra Unless you are running as root (hint: you're not, unless you're crazy) then your Opera profile won't be in `/usr/`. Try the folder starting with `/home/yourusername/` or `~/`.

Comment: i have a old login from one of my micorsoft account which i have no backup but i didn't save the password in the broswer but every time i open my browser i can directly log into the account but can;t see password in saved passwords..so if i m going to clean the system i loose the login etc now is there any way to save and export?

Comment: If your browser can log in, then it has the password in its profile. I don't think there's anywhere else it could come from. I have a really old Firefox, but Edit->Preferences->Security->Saved Logins->Show Passwords works pre-Quantum (60.0)

Comment: I tried but didn;t find any password in my opera profile that is opera verison 51 cent os .If you know how to find the pass it would be really helpful ..yes its stored somewhere some session ,i suppose but where it is i m not sure..